# Some algebra of sets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A = \{ x : f(x) > a \} $ and $B = \{ x : g(x) > a \}$.

Then $A \setminus B = \{ x : f(x) > a, \; \; \; g(x) \leq a \} \subseteq \{x : f(x) \neq g(x) \} $

$B \setminus A = \{ x : g(x) > a, \; \; \; f(x) \leq a \} \subseteq \{x : f(x) \neq g(x) \} $

Are these identities true? Can someone help me prove them?

Comment: They are true, and you shouldn’t really need any help: everything follows immediately from the definitions of $A$, $B$, and set difference. For instance, what condition on $x$ tells you that $x\notin B$?

Comment: Can we just say that since elements of $A \setminus B$ are $x's$ such that $f > g \implies f \neq g$?. And similarly for the other one.

Comment: Yes, that covers the inclusion, and a similar argument gives you the inclusion for $B\setminus A$. The equalities are even easier, if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These identities are true.

We needn't use anything but the definition of $A \setminus B$:

$$A \setminus B \stackrel{\rm def}= \{x \in A: x \notin B\} = \{x: x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B\}$$

and the recognition that if $f(x) > a$ and $g(x) \le a$, it must be that $f(x) \ne g(x)$.